# How do I append static items to a dict using Jinja2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, jinja2

If I have a list as follows:

```
[
    {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2"
    },
    {
        "a": "3",
        "b": "4"
    },
    {
        "a": "5",
        "b": "6"
    }            
]
```

How can I rename the keys of the first list and append static items to each dict using a Jijja2 filter?

For example:

```
[
    {
        "a2": "1",
        "b2": "2",
        "c2": "test"
    },
    {
        "a2": "3",
        "b2": "4",
        "c2": "test"
    },
    {
        "a2": "5",
        "b2": "6"
        "c2": "test"
    }            
]
```

I have attempted something like the following:

```
{{ my_list | map('json_query', '{a2:a, b2:b}') | list }}
```

Which is half the battle, but how would I append a static item to the resulting dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do:

```
- debug:
  msg: >-
    {{ my_list | json_query("[].{a2: a, b2: b, c2: 'test' }") }}
```

Result with a copy paste of your data:

```
    "msg": [
        {
            "a2": "1",
            "b2": "2",
            "c2": "test"
        },
        {
            "a2": "3",
            "b2": "4",
            "c2": "test"
        },
        {
            "a2": "5",
            "b2": "6",
            "c2": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The order of single and double quotes nesting matters** (See [jmespath specification](http://jmespath.org/specification.html)). If you put the single/double quotes the other way arround, the result of your static string will be `"None"`

Comment: This seems to work! I assume the `>-` is used for telling Ansible that the value is a string without having to use actual quotes, which are required for the nesting? Is there any way to pretty this up by escaping anything? (ideally so everything fits on one line)

Comment: Looks like you can! `"{{ my_list | json_query(\"[].{a2: a, b2: b, c2: 'test' }\") }}"` seems to work!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `>` is the yaml folded block marker. `-` is the chomping indicator for the block (no new line at end). See https://yaml-multiline.info/ for more explanations and info

Answer (score 0):

I would define a global python function in charge of altering the dictionaries. It would look like:

```
def some_func(my_sequence):
    new_sequence = []
    for my_dict in my_sequence:
        new_dict = {f"{key}2": value for key, value in my_dict.items()}
        new_dict.update(c2="test")
        new_sequence.append(new_dict)
    return new_sequence
```

Can be of course improved to remove hard-coding.

Once defined the Jinja2 environment I would declare a custom filter pointing to that function.

```
environment.filters["my_customfilter"] = some_func
```

And use it into the template as follow:

```
{{ my_list|my_customfilter() }}
```

Or into a loop:

```
{% for my_dict in my_list|my_customfilter() %}
    {# do something here #}
{% endfor %}
```

Or any other use.

This way the main logic is not brought by Jinja2 which is just a templating engine but by your main python script. Your code is more flexible in case of evolution.